# knockout bindings not updating element values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I am working in Knockout and I have a view model that is contains a single observable:

```
function rvwHistoryViewModel() {
    if (document.getElementById("CCHPISentence").innerHTML != "") {
        rvwHistory = ko.observable(document.getElementById("CCHPISentence").innerHTML);
    }
    else {
        rvwHistory = ko.observable("crap");
    }
}
```

Initially in the code above the `CCHPISentence.innerHTLM == ""` so the bindings are applied and my element reads "crap as it should".

However, I call this same viewModel later and at this point the `CCHPISentence.innerHTLM == "some thing"`.  I debug and see that rvwHistory is indeed set to `"some thing"`, but the value on the screen still reads `"crap"`.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance to anybody that can help me here, I have been staring at this one a while.

Comment: `ko.observable()` creates an observable. If observable exists instead of creating new one just update the value `rvmHistory('new value')`

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezs9s7g9/

Comment: What does your html look like? Specifically, what are you using for the `data-bind` attribute? Your view model function doesn't appear to be returning anything. Could you post the rest of it?

Comment: When working with databinding in knockout.js you shouldn't ever need to refer to elements by their id. That's what the data binding gives you.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. Don't explain what you are doing, explain what your *goal* is.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how your ViewModel can be. It contains an input and an example of a computed.

```js
function rvwHistoryViewModel() {
  this.CCHPISentence = ko.observable("");
  this.rvwHistory = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.CCHPISentence() == "") {
      return "crab"; // nice little animal
    } else {
      return this.CCHPISentence();
    }
  }, this);

}

ko.applyBindings(new rvwHistoryViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

CCHPISentence:
<input data-bind="value:CCHPISentence" type="text"/>
<br/>rvwHistory:<span data-bind="text:rvwHistory"></span>
```

tip, follow the excellent tutorial: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/